# Java 8- Multiple Group by Into Map of Collection

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to do a **groupingBy** on two attributes of an object with Java streams. That's easy enough as has been documented by some answers:

```
products.stream().collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Product::getUpc, 
        Collectors.groupingBy(Product::getChannelIdentifier)));
```

for example, the above snippet will produce a Map of Maps in the form

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<Product>>>
```

Where a map has keys of UPC codes and its values are maps that have keys of Channel Identifiers which reference a list of products.

That's cool, but what if I don't need the nested value to be a map? That is to say, I want to organize the nested collection by ChannelIdentifier, but I only care about the .values() of the map, not the map itself. Is there a way to get a result that matches the following?

```
Map<String, List<List<Product>>
```

Lists or collections... it doesn't matter. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The grouping operation unavoidably needs to maintain a `Map` as it has to track the key values for the grouping. But you can use the `values()` view directly:

```
Map<String, Collection<List<Product>>> m=products.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Product::getUpc, Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Product::getChannelIdentifier), Map::values)));
```

If the resulting map will have a longer lifetime and you want to reduce the required storage space, or if you need a `List`, you may copy the view into a list during that step:

```
Map<String, List<List<Product>>> map=products.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Product::getUpc, Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Product::getChannelIdentifier),
        m -> new ArrayList<>(m.values()) )));
```

Comment: Marvelous- thanks! Out of curiosity, how did you know about "collectingAndThen"? Did you memorize the API docs or do you have a good resource for this?

Comment: I memorize [the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Collectors.html) by answering SO questions and reading other’s [related answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava-8%5D+collectors+is%3Aanswer). The training is a nice side effect.